# showing progress bar in alert dialog

Tags: android

I have an alert dialog box in my application for login authentication. While sending the request i want to show a progress bar and want to dismiss if the response is success.please help me if anyone knows.Iam using the below code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LinearLayout login = new LinearLayout(this);
TextView tvUserName = new TextView(this);
TextView tvPassword = new TextView(this);
TextView tvURL = new TextView(this);
final EditText etUserName = new EditText(this);
final EditText etPassword = new EditText(this);
final EditText etURL = new EditText(this);
login.setOrientation(1); // 1 is for vertical orientation
tvUserName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.username));
tvPassword.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.password));
tvURL.setText("SiteURL");
login.addView(tvURL);
login.addView(etURL);
login.addView(tvUserName);
login.addView(etUserName);
login.addView(tvPassword);
etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
| InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
login.addView(etPassword);
alert.setView(login);
alert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.login));
alert.setCancelable(true);
alert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.login),
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
    int whichButton) {
        strhwdXml = etURL.getText().toString();
        strUserName = etUserName.getText().toString();
        XmlUtil.username = strUserName;
        strPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();
        if ((strUserName.length() == 0)
        && (strPassword.length() == 0)
        && (strhwdXml.length() == 0)) {
            Toast.makeText(
            getBaseContext(),
            getResources().getString(
            R.string.userPassword),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onStart();
            } else {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs
            .edit();
            try {
                StringBuffer inStreamBuf = new StringBuffer();
                inStreamBuf = XmlUtil
                .getLoginAuthResponse(strUserName,
                strPassword, strhwdXml);
                strXmlResponse = inStreamBuf.toString();
                Log.e("Response:", strXmlResponse);
                String parsedXML = ParseResponse(strXmlResponse);
                if (parsedXML
                .equalsIgnoreCase(getResources()
                .getString(R.string.success))) {
                }
```

Comment: Use Asynchronous Task for this, http://droidapp.co.uk/?p=177

Comment: it might be  easier if you was to define your layout in xml

Comment: how i can done this...please help me  jiduvah

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 32):

It might be easier to use this

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                        "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

You can read more about progress dialogs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog)

To cancel would be

```
    dialog.dismiss();
```

> This class was deprecated in API level 26. ProgressDialog is a modal
>   dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the app. Instead
>   of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like
>   ProgressBar, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively,
>   you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress.For more details [Click Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog)

Comment: how to cancel it if the authentication response is success?!?

Comment: that would open a new dialog, no? Is that the desired effect?  You can also add a progressdialog to the dialog itself

Comment: it would open a new dialog yes

Comment: the progress bar opens,but it wont goes if the response is success

Comment: ProgressDialog is deprecated and not useable with the appcompat libs.

Answer (score 11):

Since the `ProgressDialog` class is deprecated, here is a simple way to display `ProgressBar` in `AlertDialog`:

1. Add fields in your Activity:

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder;
   AlertDialog progressDialog;
   ```
2. Add getDialogProgressBar() method in your Activity:

   ```
   public AlertDialog.Builder getDialogProgressBar() {

     if (builder == null) {
       builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

       builder.setTitle("Loading...");

       final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       progressBar.setLayoutParams(lp);
       builder.setView(progressBar);
     }
     return builder;
   }
   ```
3. Initialize `progressDialog`:

   ```
   progressDialog = getDialogProgressBar().create();
   ```
4. Show/Hide AlertDialog whenever u want using utility methods:

   `progressDialog.show()` and `progressDialog.dismiss()`

Comment: I get an `Illegal State Exception: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` when calling `show()` when the app restarts a second time.  ??

Comment: @ScottBiggs Hi, did u get a solution for that problem or still facing the same problem?

Comment: Yes!  Unusually, it seems that the dialog can still be in memory when you restart the app.  So making sure that `builder = null` is called whenever the context is destroyed.  I added an `destroyDialog()` method to this dialog class, and I called it during the Activity's `onDestroy()` method.  Let me know if this isn't clear and I'll add it as another answer.

Comment: What's the point of `lp`? With and without it the dialog adjusts to the height of the `ProgressBar` but the width always stays the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the progress bar to show, try the following steps and also you can copy and paste the entire code the relevant portion of your code and it should work.

```
//the first thing you need to to is to initialize the progressDialog Class like this

final ProgressDialog progressBarDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);

//set the icon, title and progress style..

progressBarDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

progressBarDialog.setTitle("Showing progress...");

progressBarDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);


    //setting the OK Button
    progressBarDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                int whichButton){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //set the Cancel button
    progressBarDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
//initialize the dialog..
progressBarDialog.setProgress(0);

//setup a thread for long running processes
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        for (int i=0; i<=15; i++){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                progressBarDialog.incrementProgressBy((int)(5));
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //dismiss the dialog
        progressBarDialog.dismiss();
     }
   });

//show the dialog
progressBarDialog.show();
```

The cancel button should dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Please note that ProgressDialog is now deprecated, so one should not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
  private class DownloadingProgressTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowDescription.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
         this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
         this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {
            // write your request code here


            **StringBuffer inStreamBuf = new StringBuffer();
            inStreamBuf = XmlUtil
            .getLoginAuthResponse(strUserName,
            strPassword, strhwdXml);
            strXmlResponse = inStreamBuf.toString();
            Log.e("Response:", strXmlResponse);
            String parsedXML = ParseResponse(strXmlResponse);
            if (parsedXML
            .equalsIgnoreCase(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.success))) {**

              return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowDescription.this,
                    "File successfully downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            imgDownload.setVisibility(8);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ShowDescription.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

}
```

and call this in onclick event

```
new DownloadingProgressTask().execute();
```

Comment: can u edit my code and tell me how to  implement it in my application